# Error when tapping on an image in iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm pretty new to objective c and iOS development, and I feel sometimes like I'm banging my head into a brick wall...

I'm adding an image programmatically to the screen to server as a menu button. I have a class handling that button. This is the .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MenuButton : NSObject <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property UIImageView * menuButton;
- (id) initWithButton: (UIImageView *) mb;
- (void) onTapMenuButton;
@end
```

And this is the .m file:

```
#import "MenuButton.h"

@implementation MenuButton

- (id) initWithButton: (UIImageView *) mb {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        self.menuButton = mb;

        UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTapMenuButton)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [self.menuButton addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        tap.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) onTapMenuButton {
    NSLog(@"SUCCESS!");
}

@end
```

Whenever I tap the button, the program stops running. In the output window all I can see is some text: "(lldb)", and the editor shows me the main function, highlighting the only line I have there, which I haven't touched at all (the one created automatically when I start a single-view application).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you put the code, you are using for image view implementation on screen.

Comment: Where have you created mb? Share the code where you have created the image view mb. That is where it seems you have the problem

Comment: Side note: You'll want to make your `onTapMenuButton` method accept one parameter, a UITapGestureRecognizer so you can inspect the state of the gesture recognizer. As of right now (once you resolve your crash), that method will be called when the user first presses the image view, when they let go of the button (the one you really want), and if gesture becomes canceled. See the sample code at the top of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html . Don't forget to change the action selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you're creating a MenuButton instance, which sets up this tap gesture recognizer, but you're not retaining the the MenuButton instance and it becomes deallocated. The result: the tap gesture recognize is calling `onTapMenuButton` on an object that no longer exists.

How are you keeping hold of the MenuButton objects?

Comment: Thanks, that indeed was the problem... It takes a little getting used to, I guess. I just moved the variable holding the MenuButton instance higher up the hierarchy, and now it's working.